# Inserindo uma PROCEDURE em query() no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, funções, stored-procedures

Galera, estou há um tempo tentando integrar uma procedure juntamente com o PHP, mas ao chamá-la, o PHP continua apresentando erros:

---

Visão Geral:

```js
$database = null;

 function Conecta($server, $user, $port, $bd){
  $GLOBALS['database'] = mysql_connect($server, $user, $port);
  mysql_select_db($bd);
  if ($GLOBALS['database']) {
   return $GLOBALS['database'];
  } else {
      aviso("ERRO!");
  }
 }

 function aviso($texto){
  ?>
   <script>
    alert("<?php echo $texto ?>");
   </script>
  <?php
 }

 function CadastrarFuncionario($nome_fun, $cargo_fun, $nascimento_fun, $cpf_fun, $rg_fun, $estado_fun, $salario_fun){
  $res = $GLOBALS['database']->query("SET @nomefun = '".$nome_fun."'");
  if ($res0) {
   aviso("foi");
  }
  $res .= $GLOBALS['database']->query("SET @cargofun = '".$cargo_fun."'");
  $res2 = $GLOBALS['database']->query("SET @nascimentofun = '".$nascimento_fun."'");
  $res3 = $GLOBALS['database']->query("SET @cpfun = '".$cpf_fun."'");
  $res4 = $GLOBALS['database']->query("SET @rgfun = '".$rg_fun."'");
  $res5 = $GLOBALS['database']->query("SET @estadofun = '".$estado_fun."'");
  $res6 = $GLOBALS['database']->query("SET @salariofun = '".$salario_fun."'");


  $sql = "CALL CadastrarFuncionario(@nomefun, @cargofun, @nascimentofun, @cpfun, @rgfun, @estadofun, @salariofun);";
  $res7 = $GLOBALS['database']->query($sql);
  if ($res7) {
   aviso("funcionário cadastrado com sucesso!");
  } else {
   aviso("erro!");
  }
 }

 function CadastrarDependente($nome_dep, $nascimento_dep, $funcionario_dep, $parentesco_dep, $conexao){
  $res = mysqli_query($conexao, "CALL CadastrarDependente ('".$nome_dep."', '".$nascimento_dep."', ".$funcionario_dep.", '".$parentesco_dep."')", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
  if ($res) {
   aviso("dependente cadastrado com sucesso!");
  } else {
   aviso("erro!");
  }
 }
```

Porém, não sei se o problema está no código ou na lógica de programação, mas esta procedure que foi chamada está programada esta maneira:

---

Tabelas e Procedures no MySQL:

---

```js
CREATE TABLE funcionario (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 cargo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
 cpf CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 rg CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 estado CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 salario DOUBLE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dependente (
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 nome VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
 funcionario_id INT NOT NULL,
 parentesco CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (funcionario_id) REFERENCES funcionario (id)
);

# cadastrar

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CadastrarFuncionario (IN nome_fun VARCHAR(100), IN cargo_fun VARCHAR(50), IN nascimento_fun DATE, IN cpf_fun CHAR(20), IN rg_fun CHAR(20), IN estado_fun CHAR(50), IN salario_fun DOUBLE)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO funcionario VALUES (null, nome_fun, cargo_fun, nascimento_fun, cpf_fun, rg_fun, estado_fun, salario_fun);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE CadastrarDependente (IN nome_dep VARCHAR(100), IN nascimento_dep DATE, IN funcionario_dep INT, IN parentesco_dep CHAR(50))
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO dependente VALUES (null, nome_dep, nascimento_dep, funcionario_dep, parentesco_dep);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

E no servidor, o PHP está insistindo no mesmo erro:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Problema: Qual(is) são os erros que está fazendo o servidor retornar este aviso. E qual(is) seriam as boas práticas para criar uma procedure normal e chamá-la pelo PHP

Comment: Por favor, coloque os códigos como texto ao invés de imagens.

Comment: @CypherPotato *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não está sendo feito o bind correto dos parâmetros, pode fazer assim:

```
// declara o sql
$sql = "CALL CadastrarFuncionario(@nomefun, @cargofun, @nascimentofun, @cpfun, @rgfun, @estadofun, @salariofun);";

// prepara a execucao da procedure
$res7 = $GLOBALS['database']->prepare($sql);

// passa os parametros
$res7->bindParam($nome_fun, $cargo_fun, $nascimento_fun, $cpf_fun, $rg_fun, $estado_fun, $salario_fun);

// executa
$res7->execute();
```

Comment: eu tentei executar estes comandos no banco e deu o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\Users\user\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.6\root\recuperacao - tpi\funcs.php on line 25

Comment: Eu costumo usar estes comandos de Orientação a Objetos quando eu utilizo a classe PDO(), que possui um conjuntos de funcionalidades e métodos que fazem estes serviços. Neste caso, eu estou tentando cadastrar o funcionário da maneira mais simples possível, mas até agora não consigo compreender a forma que o PHP trata das procedures do MySQL e como eu posso utilizar das boas práticas para chamar uma procedure corretamente nesta função.